# assigning value to hidden field from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to do what seems to be simple but am unable to accomplish

I am trying to set the value of a column after a row focus change in a grid to a hidden value in java script.

My imbedded javascript code:

```
function OnGridFocusedRowChanged() {
   grdA.GetRowValues(grdA.GetFocusedRowIndex(), 'ClientID', OnGetRowValues);
}

function OnGetRowValues(values) {
  //Set hidden value
  document.getElementById('<%=hdnClientID.ClientID%>').value = values[0];

  //Fire button click
  btnPopulateGrids_Click();        
}
```

where `hdnClientID` is the name of my hidden field

In GridA I have the setting as such that `OnGridFocusedRowChanged` gets executed each time a row focus change takes place.

To this point, it works fine, the `values[0]` in `OnGetRowValues()` contains the correct value from the corresponding row in GridA.

But in the  corresponding code behind, I cannot access the value from hidden field `hdnClientID`.  Always comes up null when accessing

```
Current_Client_ID = CInt(hdnClientID.Value);
```

cannot access or convert any value from 
    hdnClientID.ClientID.

either.

I'm missing something simple.

Comment: Did you add `runat=server` to your hidden field?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Currently, there is not enough information to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had to complete a similar task recently and I too was unable to access the value from codebehind. I researched and found out that it is not that simple and that you can't do it with javascript. What I would recommend is to check if you have jQuery installed and if you do, change your function to this:

```
function OnGetRowValues(values) {
  //Set hidden value
  $('#<%=hdnClientID.ClientID%>').val(values[0]);

  //Fire button click
  btnPopulateGrids_Click();

  //If you change your HiddenField to have OnValueChange event, you can trigger it with this
  //__doPostBack('<%= CompanyCode.ClientID %>', '');        
}
```

Also, I guess you are firing some function from code behind with `btnPopulateGrids_Click();`.
I would recommend adding `OnValueChanged="hdnClientID_OnValueChanged"/>` to your `<asp:HiddenField/>` and using my supplied function triggering method.

Comment: jQuery, being a javascript library, uses vanilla javascript under the hood. jQuery just does the vanilla javascript on your behalf and handles browser compatability so that you dont have to. If your statement were correct, then jQuery would not work either.